# Maximum no of acceptances in an universal preference of Gale-Shapley?

Tags: algorithms

If there are 3 men(M1, M2, M3) and 3 women (W1, W2, W3) all with the same universal accepted order of preference say for men M1 > M2 > M3 and W1 > W2 > W3, what would be the maximum possible no of acceptance by say women if men propose first.
My thought would be for n men and n women, a maximum number of accepted offers in one run can be n.

Comment: Well, you have the exact preferences for everyone involved, so you can see exactly what happens in the algorithm. Have you tried this?

Comment: I have, but the answer isn't n times, in this case, n=3 according to my logic, but it's not the answer

Comment: Apologies for the confusing reply. By running the algorithm on the given set starting with M1, I only get 3 acceptances, M1-W1 M2-W2 and M3-W3. Since you said you get 6, Am i misunderstanding the meaning of accepted offers. What I understand is that an accepted offer is every offer given by a M AND accepted by a W .

Comment: Oh, hm. Actually, you are right, and the number of accepted offers should be $3$... If that's not the "right answer" according to some answer key, then I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Yea it should be3. But would it be the maximum though? Like if we start assigning from M2, i.e M2-W1, which would ultimately change, it would give us 5 accepted offers.

Comment: If you "start assigning from M2", then either you're not using Gale-Shapley, or your preference order is different from the one you've stated.